# Conditional script with for non existing column (yet)?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL server for creating script to run in production .

If a table doesn't contain a specific column, then create that column.

I've already did that :

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
       WHERE  COLUMN_NAME = 'SeeMaxDaysBackwardPrice'
              AND TABLE_NAME = 'tblsubscriptiontype'
   )
BEGIN

    ALTER TABLE dbo.tblsubscriptiontype ADD SeeMaxDaysBackwardPrice INT NULL

END
```

But now  I want to insert a new row to that modified table . So now my script looks like this :

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
       WHERE  COLUMN_NAME = 'SeeMaxDaysBackwardPrice'
              AND TABLE_NAME = 'tblsubscriptiontype'
   )
BEGIN


    ALTER TABLE dbo.tblsubscriptiontype ADD SeeMaxDaysBackwardPrice INT NULL


    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblSubscriptionType] ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblSubscriptionType]
      (
       ...
        [SeeMaxDaysBackwardPrice]      <-------- ERROR
      )
    SELECT ...
           -365


    COMMIT;
    RAISERROR (
        N'[dbo].[tblSubscriptionType]: Insert Batch: 1.....Done!',
        10,
        1
    ) 
    WITH NOWAIT;


    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblSubscriptionType] OFF;
END
GO
```

But now I get an error ( which I perfectlly understand) :

> ```
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
> Invalid column name 'SeeMaxDaysBackwardPrice'.
> ```

Sure I can split the script into 2 seperate scripts , but then I'll have this condition twice :

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
       WHERE  COLUMN_NAME = 'SeeMaxDaysBackwardPrice'
              AND TABLE_NAME = 'tblsubscriptiontype'
   )
```

**Question:**

Is there any way to make SQL more relaxed about a column that do not exists yet ? (I already know about dynamic query (text) , but I wonder if there is another option.

Comment: You can separate batches with a `GO` line, that should be enough I think.

Comment: @DavidG https://i.imgur.com/c0P24DR.jpg

Comment: @RoyiNamir your `BEGIN` still needs an `END` in that batch.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the code in dynamic T-SQL statement:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
       WHERE  COLUMN_NAME = 'SeeMaxDaysBackwardPrice'
              AND TABLE_NAME = 'tblsubscriptiontype'
   )
BEGIN


    ALTER TABLE dbo.tblsubscriptiontype ADD SeeMaxDaysBackwardPrice INT NULL


    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblSubscriptionType] ON;


    DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = N'

     INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblSubscriptionType]
      (
       ...
        [SeeMaxDaysBackwardPrice]      
      )
    SELECT ...
           -365

    ';

    BEGIN TRY

        BEGIN TRAN;

        EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement; 

        COMMIT TRAN;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        ROLLBACK TRAN;

    END CATCH




    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblSubscriptionType] OFF;
END
GO
```

Comment: _(I already know about dynamic query (text) , but I wonder if there is another option._

Comment: @RoyiNamir You are getting an error with severity 16 - this severity "Indicate errors that can be corrected by the user.", so we need somehow to lie the engine everything is fine prior the execution.